# A path to combinatorics by andreescu

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ordered triples of sets $(A,B,C)$ such that $A \cup B \cup C=\{1,2,3,\cdots,2003\}$ and $A \cap B \cap C=\varnothing$.

I tried it but was unable to figure it out

Comment: I tried it each element goes for either A or B or C or (both A and B) or (both A and C) or ( both B and C).    That means each element has 6 places to go. So, the answer can be 6^2003

Comment: But I don't have the answer so I can't be sure

Comment: That's right, the answer is $6^{2003}$.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation